# Grouping data based on subject ids to get a max value and then subtracting that value for each subjects data point

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has all the data for multiple participants. As part of the data clean-up I need to make all of the participants baseline data collection session numbers negative. To make it a little more complicated each participant completed either 4 or 5 baseline data collections.

Basically I need to get the max session number for each participant add 1 to it and than subtract it from each participants session number. Below is how far I have gotten but I am missing the final step

```
    data_tibble     
A tibble: 49,657 × 54       
    SID     Session
1   User1   1
    100s of rows for Session 1  
2   User1   2
    …   
    100 rows for each Session for each User
```

Running distinct on the data you can see each user and their number of sessions some users have a total of 4 sessions while others have 5. I would like to take the max session for each user add 1 and subtract from each of their data points in data_tibble.

```
distinct(data_tibble, SID, Session)     
     SID    Session 
    <chr>   <int>
1   User1   1
2   User1   2
3   User1   3
4   User1   4
5   User1   5
6   User2   1
7   User2   2
8   User2   3
9   User2   4
10  User3   1
# ... with 38 more rows
```

I figured that I should group_by SID and then grab the max session number for each group. This gives me the max Session value for each SID but now I don't know how to go back to my original 49k data_tibble and subtract the max(Session) based on the SID

```
group <- group_by(data_tibble, SID)
distinct(group, max(Session))       
    `max(Session)`  SID
    <int>   <chr>
1   5   User1
2   4   User2
3   4   User3
4   4   User4
5   4   User5
6   4   User6
7   4   User7
8   5   User8
9   5   User9
10  5   User10
11  9   User11
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example--provide a few lines of the dataset, or create a sample dataset that mimics the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following would be what you are after. I created a data frame based on `distinct(data_tibble, SID, Session)`, and called it `mydf`. After defining groups, I searched the maximum number of `Session`. I added one to the number and subtracted each session number from it.

```
mydf %>%
group_by(SID) %>%
mutate(maximum = max(Session),
       subtraction = maximum + 1 - Session)

#     SID Session maximum subtraction
#  <fctr>   <int>   <int>    <dbl>
#1  User1       1       5        5
#2  User1       2       5        4
#3  User1       3       5        3
#4  User1       4       5        2
#5  User1       5       5        1
#6  User2       1       4        4
#7  User2       2       4        3
#8  User2       3       4        2
#9  User2       4       4        1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it on Jan 3rd when I am back in the office

Comment: Let me know hot it goes.

Comment: I couldn't wait till I got back to the office so I tried it with a sample set of the data and it worked! I had not thought of piping the information using mutate, which is what was needed.

Comment: I am glad to hear that!